# Bootstrap - d-flex doesn't work with a minimal HTML code

Tags: html, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am starting a Bootstrap web site and I have already a problem that I can't resolve even with minimal HTML and one flex item (which is the only element on the web site) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Association Capucine - Gagner contre la leucémie</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>
  <main>
  </main>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks per advance

Comment: what is not working? Also, what is the current output and your expected output>

Comment: I guess you forgot to include the library
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include Bootstrap CSS and Bootstrap JS.

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Association Capucine - Gagner contre la leucémie</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-around">
    <div class="p-2 bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-warning">Flex item 2</div>
    <div class="p-2 bg-primary">Flex item 3</div>
  </div>

  <main>
  </main>

  <footer>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow!! I am very nul !
Thank you very much !